# ICE Failed in firefox in case of different network wbrtc

Tags: firefox, webrtc, firefox-developer-tools, turn

I am using TURN server with my webrtc application.It works fine in chrome in both same network and different network.But in firefox it works fine in same network but in case of different network it shows error:

```
ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
```

webrtc log:

```
(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): relay only option results in no host candidate for IP4:10.16.241.33:0/UDP

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): relay only option results in no host candidate for IP4:10.32.4.48:0/UDP

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): relay only option results in ICE TCP being disabled

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) specified too many components

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) specified bogus candidate

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) has no stream matching stream 0-1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts) aLevel=1

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) no streams with non-empty check lists

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) no streams with pre-answer requests

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) no checks to start

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): Message does not correspond to any registered stun ctx

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP lifetime=3600

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): setting pair to state FROZEN: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts))/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): Pairing candidate IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP (57e1fff):IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP (57c1fff) priority=395226047563186174 (57c1fff0afc3ffe)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/ICE-STREAM(0-1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts) aLevel=0): Starting check timer for stream.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): setting pair to state WAITING: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)): Creating permission for IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) is now checking

(ice/WARNING) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default): no pairs for 0-1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts) aLevel=0

(stun/WARNING) Inconsistent message method: 103 expected 008

(stun/WARNING) Inconsistent message method: 103 expected 001

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): Message does not correspond to any registered stun ctx

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) Inconsistent message method: 108 expected 001

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): Message does not correspond to any registered stun ctx

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): peer (PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.16.241.33:63522/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)::TURN): Timed out

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:10.16.241.33:63522/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)): mode 20, nr_turn_client_error_cb

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:10.16.241.33:63522/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)) failed

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:10.16.241.33:63522/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)): cancelling

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:10.16.241.33:63522/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)): nr_turn_allocated_cb called with state 4

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:10.16.241.33:63522/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:3478/UDP)): nr_turn_allocated_cb failed

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)): Timed out

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): setting pair to state FAILED: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/STREAM(0-1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): triggered check on l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): received STUN check on failed pair, resurrecting: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): setting pair to state WAITING: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts):default)/CAND-PAIR(l0AQ): Inserting pair to trigger check queue: l0AQ|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49963/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:10.32.4.48:63523/UDP|IP4:52.9.27.168:49256/UDP)|candidate:3 1 UDP 92020735 52.9.27.168 49963 typ relay raddr 52.9.27.168 rport 49963)

(stun/INFO) Responding with error 400: ICE Failure

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1480060743115000 (id=119 url=https://172.26.203.112:8889/amit_new/index-rui-dev.jsp#app/contacts)): Message does not correspond to any registered stun ctx

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

Now i am totally confused where is the problem.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. :(

Comment: i have the same problem :(

Comment: Hey I faced some similar problem, can you please provide solution to this?